# Single page WordPress site with comments box

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a site in wordpress that consists of only one single page (index.php). Each section of the page loops and brings in content from a certain post (based on its id). One section also has a comment box as well as the post content, along with posted comments. However, the problem I have is that once a comment has been posted (send button clicked), it loads single.php. The idea is that there are no permalinks on the site and only content of posts are displayed, hence keeping the user on the index page only. What kind go code would I need to add so that posting a comment does not load single.php, and therefore would reload index.php?

Thanks.

Edit:
Just to give an example of the code I am using:
On index.php I am using:

```
<?php $category = array('category_name' => 'My category'); ?>
<?php query_posts($category); ?>
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="articleWrap">
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

and on the section I want the comments box:

```
<?php $other_category = array('category_name' => 'My other category'); ?>
<?php query_posts($other_category); ?>
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="articleWrap">
        <?php the_content(); ?>
        <?php $withcomments = 1; comments_template(); ?>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

The code for my comments template (comments.php) that I call in is:

```
<div class="messageBox">
<?php
$comments_args = array(
    'comment_notes_after' => '',
    'label_submit'=>'Submit',
    'title_reply' => '',
    'logged_in_as' => '',
    'comment_field' => '<p class="comment-form-comment"><label for="comment"></label><br /><textarea id="comment" name="comment" aria-required="true"></textarea></p>',
);
comment_form($comments_args);
?>
</div>  <!-- //messageBox -->
<div class="commentBoxesWrap">
    <?php wp_list_comments('type=comment&callback=showcomments'); //this is a call back to a function in functions.php ?>
</div>  <!-- //commentBoxesWrap -->
```

Comment: use ajax? give more details about your code, how comment is posted?

Comment: Is that comment box thing a plugin you wrote?

Comment: sinhayash is right: you need to use jquery/ajax (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/). Is someone clicks on the submit button, a ajax call will made to single.php (?) which saves the post and sends back the content or the formated html - this info can be placed with jquery append (http://api.jquery.com/append/)

Comment: Thank you all for replying. I edited my question with some code just to give a bit more info, but I will look into query ajax. Is there anything I need to know in regards to using it with wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery and AJAX to onLoad, pull all the comments data (Presumably name, date and comment?) from whatever you PHP function is. You would be probably use a GET request but if you want to have date filters, you would use a POST request and pass the filters as arguments. You are effectively making an API.

jQuery:

```js
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "http://example.com/comment-load.php",
       data: {
           date: filter_date,
           tag: filter_tag
       },
       dataType: "json"
   })
       .done(function (comment) {
       var i = 0;
       var leg = $(comment).length;
       while (i < leg) {
           $("#comments").append("<div>" + comment[i] + "</div>");
           i = i + 1;
       }
  });
```

And the PHP:

> echo json_encode($arr);

$arr has your comments in it